# Why appendChild() makes some child missing?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

```js
const div1 = document.createElement('div'),
    div2 = document.createElement('div')
div1.innerHTML = '<br>x'
div1.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    // text node x is missing
    console.log('child:', child)
    // magic line here
    div2.appendChild(child)
})
// finally, only <br> is seen
console.log(div2.innerHTML)
```

As is seen, the text node `x` is gone.
If it's `appendChild()` that makes a difference, why does it treat the element node and text node differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the iteration, or more specifically, in the fact that you're modifying the node list while iterating over it.

As noted on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> **Note:** If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the
> document, `appendChild()` moves it from its current position to the
> new position.

In your first iteration, by calling `div2.appendChild(child)` on the `<br>` node, this node is effectively removed from `div1` and the size of the `div1.childNodes` list is reduced to one (containing only the `x` text node). The iteration pointer, however, has already moved past the first element, hence your `x` text node is not being printed to the console.

You'd see exactly the same behavior if you modified an array that you were looping over with `forEach()`:

```js
const array = ['<br>', 'x'];

array.forEach((v) => {
  console.log(v);
  array.splice(0, 1);
});
```